# Elixir errors using `inet_res` library

Tags: erlang, elixir

I have some trouble with `inet_res` from Erlang. I tried to use it from my Elixir shell and also from my Erlang shell but I have unexpected behaviour. Sometimes I'm able to lookup a domain, sometimes I don't have the return value:

```
iex(1)> :inet_res.lookup('disneur.me', :in, :mx)
[]
iex(2)> :inet_res.lookup('disneur.me', :in, :mx)
[]
iex(3)> :inet_res.lookup('disneur.me', :in, :mx)
[{1, 'aspmx.l.google.com'}, {10, 'alt3.aspmx.l.google.com'},
 {10, 'alt4.aspmx.l.google.com'}, {5, 'alt1.aspmx.l.google.com'},
 {5, 'alt2.aspmx.l.google.com'}]
```

As you can see the first two times I called it, it returned an empty array and the thrid time, it returned the good value.

I tried to add in 4th parameters `retry: 5` and also `timeout: 10` but it doesn't help:

```
:inet_res.lookup('disneur.me', :in, :mx, timeout: 10, retry: 5)
[]
iex(2)> :inet_res.lookup('disneur.me', :in, :mx, timeout: 10, retry: 5)
[{1, 'aspmx.l.google.com'}, {10, 'alt3.aspmx.l.google.com'},
 {10, 'alt4.aspmx.l.google.com'}, {5, 'alt1.aspmx.l.google.com'},
 {5, 'alt2.aspmx.l.google.com'}]
```

I also tried directly from erlang shell and I have exactly the same behaviour:

```
1> inet_res:lookup("disneur.me", in, mx, [{timeout, 10}, {retry, 5}]).
[]
2> inet_res:lookup("disneur.me", in, mx, [{timeout, 10}, {retry, 5}]).
[]
3> inet_res:lookup("disneur.me", in, mx, [{timeout, 10}, {retry, 5}]).
[]
4> inet_res:lookup("disneur.me", in, mx, [{timeout, 10}, {retry, 5}]).
[{1,"aspmx.l.google.com"},
 {10,"alt3.aspmx.l.google.com"},
 {10,"alt4.aspmx.l.google.com"},
 {5,"alt1.aspmx.l.google.com"},
 {5,"alt2.aspmx.l.google.com"}]
```

Do you know why I have such unpredictable behaviour? Do I use this library the wrong way?

EDIT:
For information, I tried with other domains (i.e: gmail.com) and I have the same issue. Other people also tried this code on their own computer and in different location. I also have the same failure on Circle-CI.

EDIT2:
A copy-paste from a discussion I had on Slack (Elixir team)

**troush [8:45 PM]** It is working fine for my domain. Maybe this issue domain specific?

**kdisneur [8:47 PM]** 
did you try several times? I mean killing you session and retrying because sometimes it works, sometimes it doesn't.

**troush [8:54 PM]**

```
iex(35)> :inet_res.lookup('google.com', :in, :mx)
[{30, 'alt2.aspmx.l.google.com'}, {40, 'alt3.aspmx.l.google.com'},
 {50, 'alt4.aspmx.l.google.com'}, {10, 'aspmx.l.google.com'},
 {20, 'alt1.aspmx.l.google.com'}]
iex(36)> :inet_res.lookup('google.com', :in, :mx)
[{40, 'alt3.aspmx.l.google.com'}, {50, 'alt4.aspmx.l.google.com'},
 {10, 'aspmx.l.google.com'}, {20, 'alt1.aspmx.l.google.com'},
 {30, 'alt2.aspmx.l.google.com'}]
iex(37)> :inet_res.lookup('google.com', :in, :mx)
[{50, 'alt4.aspmx.l.google.com'}, {10, 'aspmx.l.google.com'},
 {20, 'alt1.aspmx.l.google.com'}, {30, 'alt2.aspmx.l.google.com'},
 {40, 'alt3.aspmx.l.google.com'}]
```

**troush [8:55 PM]** Maybe a connection isssue.

**kdisneur [8:56 PM]** yes when you are in a session and it's working once, I have the same result than you. That's why I was asking about restarting a new Elixir shell

**troush [8:59 PM]** Oh, okay, i understand. Yes, i got this issue on broad new iex session. Empty responses, but only on your domain. On gmail/google.com it works perfctly

**troush ​[9:01]** And i got same issue on my custom domain.  So there some issue with this :simple_smile: sorry for disonanse

So I don't think it's coming from my network or for a specific domain. I think it's really about the way I use this library.

Thanks for your help

Comment: I tried this in both `iex` and `erl` and it works for me every time.

Comment: did you start a new `iex` or `erl` session between your tries? I mean, if I start a session and it works fine, if I retry the same call over and over (in the same session), it will continue to work BUT if I stop my session, start a new one, sometimes it works, sometimes it doesn't.

Comment: Yes, I see what you mean. Trying again showed the results are sometimes empty. I suggest raising your timeout option to 30.

Comment: erl -eval 'timer:sleep(5000), io:format("~p~n", [inet_res:lookup("erlang.org", in, mx)]).'

Try this: a 5 second timeout always works, but a 1-4 does not. without a timeout it fails reliably for me. Is there some kernel or stdlib dependency that hasn't started up yet that could be tested for first?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a race condition.  You're requesting data from something that doesn't exist yet.  At VM initialization inet_db needs to grab a list of resolvers.  You're making that query before that process completes.

To 'fast-track':

```
iex(1)>  :inet_db.add_ns({4,2,2,1}) ; :inet_res.lookup('disneur.me', :in, :mx)
[{10, 'alt3.aspmx.l.google.com'}, {10, 'alt4.aspmx.l.google.com'},
{5, 'alt1.aspmx.l.google.com'}, {5, 'alt2.aspmx.l.google.com'},
{1, 'aspmx.l.google.com'}]
```